# Excel VBA Column number of Listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have the ListBox1 defined with RowSource.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
MsgBox ListBox1.ListIndex
End sub
```

With this I receive the the row. Is it possible to read to Column number of the Item?

Edit:

```
|Header1|Header2|Header3|...|
|value1 |value2 |value3
|       |       |valueX
```

I want the table Position of valueX. so:

```
rowNR= ListBox1.ListIndex   //Result=1
colNr=???                  //Result=2 (if it also starts with 0)
```

Comment: The column number based on what? Your question is not very clear. A column cannot be "selected" like a row can. It's not a grid control.

Comment: You might be able to do some fancy math using the x-co-ordinate when the user clicks on a row to figure out what column they clicked on. Is that what you mean?